# Declaring variable in stored procedures and MySQL injections

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I have this situation for example:

```
id       value
 1       data_1
 2       20
 3       data_3
 4       15
 5       data_4
 6       data_6
```

and the following stored procedure:

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE PROCEDURE `test_2`.`test_procedure` (val int(9))
BEGIN

select * from `test` where `value` = val;

END
```

if I call the procedure like that

```
 call test_procedure(20);
```

I have the following result:

```
id     value
 2     20
```

Everything is ok until now.

But the thing I cannot understand is that when I call the procedure like that:

```
call test_procedure("abc");
```

I have the following result:

```
id       value
 1       data_1
 3       data_3
 5       data_4
 6       data_6
```

Is this a normal behavior of the MySQL database?

If I declare the variable “val” as integer, doesn’t this prevent MySQL injection?

I expect to have a warning or something that tells me that the input value is not an integer and the procedure to stop, not to reveal all the values in the tables that are not numbers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As for the strange results, it may be due to MySQL casting the `val` parameter and the `value` column to integer:

```
SELECT CAST("abc" AS SIGNED); -- returns 0
SELECT CAST("data_1" AS SIGNED); -- also returns 0
```

So, if you treat "abc" and "data_1" as integers in MySQL, they're equal. Just a theory but it seems to fit.

If zero happens to be an invalid value for `test.value`, you could throw an exception in your procedure if `val` is zero. If not, you'll need some other sort of workaround.

BTW, I agree with tadman that you don't have an injection threat here.

Comment: Isn’t this situation almost equal with the following syntax: “’abc’ or 1=1” where this syntax always evaluates to true and the result will be all the data from the table? In my case the result will be all the data from the table apart the numbers, and will give the information to the persons that don’t have to see them. Maybe it is not an injection but in my opinion is a serious problem of security.

Comment: You're right - it's similar to injection in that it'll give a user more than they should see. I've got an idea for a solution; I'll add it to my answer shortly.

Comment: Tadman is right. It evaluate with 0. Also this query (I test it) give the same result: “select * from `test` where `value` = 0;” I think the solution will be to check if the variable “val” is different from 0 and if it is to go ahead with the sql query, else to stop.

Comment: @Catalin - sorry about the delay posting an answer; something came up. Yes, if 0 is an invalid value for `val` then you can just have the procedure check for zero and throw an exception or return no results. Are you good to go like that?

Comment: For sure I will check if the value is not equal with 0 if there is no other workaround and I’m “glad” that I discover that, but I want to understand why it is happening. It is a bug or it is something that is known and has to be avoided?

Comment: I think it's as @tadman and I mentioned - because the parameter is type `int` MySQL is casting `val` and `test.value` to int. If they're not valid numbers they both end up being zero, and therefore equal.

Comment: Just had a thought - what if you make your parameter type `varchar(length of test.value)`? You still won't have an injection threat, and this "zero" problem will go away. Can you give it a try?

Comment: I changed this “val int(9)” into this “val varchar(50)” and is ok. But what about the normal query outside of a stored procedure? This query “select * from test where value = 0” will still give the wrong results. My conclusion is that inside of a stored procedure if you need to work with integer in some cases it is wrong to define a variable as integer. Anyway thank you very much for your answers.

Answer (score 1):

[SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/) usually come about by allowing arbitrary user data to be inserted into a query string. In this case, `val` refers to a value, not an arbitrary string. If you were using `CONCAT` to compose the query, you could be in serious trouble. In this case it looks like you're okay.

As you've written it, even if `val` was, somehow, `'; DROP DATABASE db; --` then it would be compared on a string basis, not as an actual inline string. This would be no worse than having that kind of thing in a column and performing a comparison on it.

What you're seeing is probably the conversion of an arbitrary string to `0` internally, so your `"abc"` matches against anything else that evaluates to `0`.

Comment: It is true. It evaluate with 0. I don’t understand why the where clause “where value = 0” gives all the records that are not numbers. It shouldn’t return any result? None of the data stored in value column are equal to 0.

Comment: It might end up being `WHERE CONVERT(value, SIGNED)=CONVERT(val, SIGNED)` which is `WHERE 0=0` since alphabetic characters are converted to 0.